# Nmap , host discovery

Tags: host, discovery, nmap

How can I find all hosts that are up, and display **only**

Nman scan report for xxxx.xxxx.xxxx (ip address)
Host is up(latency)
**MAC Address** -mac adress-(company)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your targets are directly connected:

```
nmap -n -sn <targets>
```

(no rDNS, ping scan)